# Highlighting particular regions of a scatterplot in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to discuss a scatter plot and would like to refer to particular regions of the plot. Is there any way to 'highlight' particular sections of the plot? Perhaps with boxes and labels as below?

```
set.seed(1410)
dsmall<-diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 100), ]
df<-data.frame("x"=dsmall$carat, "y"=dsmall$price)

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) 
p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: While this can be done with ggplot. Is it really necesary to do it that way? I think it would be a hell lot faster doing in a image editing tool.

Comment: @iselzer Surely that depends on your objective? For a once-off, I agree that putting it in a vector drawing tool is preferred, but for repeatable analysis, possibly automating tasks for multiple segments in a report, using a couple of lines of code to achieve this outcome seems like a trivial thing to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a single region, it's easiest to use `annotate`, first with `rect`, then `text`:

```
p + annotate("rect", xmin=1.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=12500, ymax= 18000, 
             fill=NA, colour="red") +
    annotate("text", x=1.75, y=17000, label="Region A", size=8)
```

[image]

---

For multiple regions, you can put the data into a data frame and use `geom_text` and `geom_rect`:

```
regions <- data.frame(
  xmin=c(1.5, 1, 0),
  xmax=c(2.5, 2, 1),
  ymin=c(12500, 5000, 0),
  ymax=c(17500, 12500, 5000),
  x   =c(2, 1.5, 0.5),
  y   =c(15000, 7500, 2500),
  lab = paste("Region", LETTERS[1:3])
)

p + 
  geom_rect(data=regions, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), 
            fill=NA, colour="red") +
  geom_text(data=regions, aes(x=x, y=y, label=lab))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thanks. So much better than having to resort to a secondary graphics software!

Comment: I know this is old, but what is the "p +" idiom being used in this example?

Comment: @chris `p` was defined in the original question.  My answer simply adds ggplot layers to this pre-existing object.