# Adding text to a plot axes without removing existing axes labels in r

Tags: r, plot, label, axes

I have the following plot

```
xleft<-c(1,2,3)
xright<-c(2,3,4)
ybottom<-c(1,2,3)
ytop<-c(2,3,4)

plot(c(1,4),c(1,4),type="n",main="title",xlab="site.x",ylab="ylab")
rect(xleft,ybottom,xright,ytop,col=c("blue","red","green"))
```

I would like to add rather long species names to both axes using these positions and labels

```
#Label position along  axes
x.label.position<-(xleft+xright)/2
y.label.position<-(ybottom+ytop)/2

#Labels
x.label<-c("Long species Name1","Long species Name2","Long species Name3")
x.label<-c("Long species Name4","Long species Name5","Long species Name5")
```

I would like to have the numerical axes, and axes titles left in place. I would also like to add a legend. So the final product would look something like this

[image]

What is the best way to go about this without having to clear the axes entirely using

```
par(xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

and adding text? Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the way to do it, and R FAQ 7.27 "How can I create rotated axis labels?" agrees, is to make space in the margin and then add the long label text.

```
 mx=12
 my=12
 par(mar = c(mx,my, 4, 2) + 0.1)
 plot(c(1,4),c(1,4),type="n",main="title",xlab="site.x",ylab="ylab")
 rect(xleft,ybottom,xright,ytop,col=c("blue","red","green"))
 text(par()$usr[1]-0.5,y.label.position,y.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1)
 text(y=par()$usr[3]-0.5,x=x.label.position,x.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1,srt=90)
```

You'll need to tweak `mx` and `my` for the length of your strings, and maybe also adjust the negative offsets in the text to stop it clashing with the labels. Note also the use of `xpd=TRUE` to stop drawing being clipped to the figure region. This is also the key to getting the legend in place:

```
 par(xpd=TRUE)
 legend(locator(1),legend=c("Species A","Species B","Species C"),
                             fill=c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

Then click where you want the legend - or replace `locator(1)` with `list(x=-0.7,y=0.6)`

You might find an easier approach with the `ggplot` package.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Spacedman is great, but I just wanted to provide one update. His code (at least for me) plots the axis labels over the tick labels. To change where the labels are positioned, you need to look at `par("mfg")`. I think the following code does what you want, more or less:

```
par(mai=c(2.5, 2.25, 0.82, 0.42), mgp=c(9, 1, 0))
plot(c(1,4), c(1,4), xaxp=c(1,4,3), yaxp=c(1,4,3), type="n", 
  main="title", xlab="site.x", ylab="ylab")
rect(xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop, col=c("blue","red","green"))
axis(1, at=x.label.position, labels=x.label, las=2)
axis(2, at=y.label.position, labels=y.label, las=2)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(x=0.25, y=0.75, 
  legend=c("Text", "Text", "Text"),
  fill=c("blue", "red", "green"),
  title="Legend")
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

As @Spacedman suggested, many of these alterations to the margins and axes are a bit more straight-forward in the `ggplot2` package (once you get used to it...!).

Comment: I have played with ggplot2 a little bit in the past. What would be the general approach to this problem using ggplot2 do you think?

Comment: For playing with the margin characteristics, I'd start by looking here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/opts.html. For the plotted items, I'd look either start here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/geom_rect.html or in this great answer to a question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954983/1088647.